# web3py The method eth_getRawTransactionByHash does not exist/is not available

Tags: ethereumjs, infura, python, raw-transaction

I am trying to run a simple command w3.eth.get_raw_transaction - this somehow works on the Binance smart chain, but does not work on infura.

```
tx_hash = "0x8dcc5116a366df826e07097720625a275e66ca8e9a3b6cdff82be04d86ddf6ea"
raw_data = w3.eth.get_raw_transaction(tx_hash)
```

I am getting this message:

```
raise ValueError(response["error"])
```

ValueError: {'code': -32601, 'message': 'The method eth_getRawTransactionByHash does not exist/is not available'}

Comment: The command `eth_getRawTransactionByHash` isn't part of the official api https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API.

Answer (score 1):

This method is not supported by the Infura API according to this thread in their forums https://community.infura.io/t/the-method-eth-getrawtransactionbyhash-does-not-exist/3821/2